# How to parse JSON data from SQLite3 to use in angular app?

Tags: json, angular, sqlite

I pulled the data from SQLite3 as JSON object so that I could have results in JSON format that also includes arrays. My SQLite3 query is the following:

```
let sql =  `SELECT json_object('id', id, 'company_id', company_id, 'title', title, 'link', link, 'domain', domain,
    'tags', 
    (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('tag_id', t.id, 'corporate_statement_link_id', t.corporate_statement_link_id, 'name', t.name)) 
    FROM tags as t
    LEFT JOIN corporate_statements c
    on c.corporate_statement_link_id = s.id
    WHERE t.corporate_statement_link_id = c.corporate_statement_link_id )) AS statement
    FROM search_results as s
    WHERE s.company_id = ?`

    db.all(sql, [id], (err, row) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        console.log("Row: ", row);
        res.send(row);
    });
```

This result was returned as JSON object using express router. However, the data it returns is in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":1,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Making a Difference in Racial Equity\",\"link\":\"https://corporate.walmart.com/newsroom/2020/06/05/making-a-difference-in-racial-equity\",\"domain\":\"corporate.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[{\"tag_id\":4,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"box\"},{\"tag_id\":2,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"ceo\"},{\"tag_id\":3,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"letter\"},{\"tag_id\":1,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"statement\"},{\"tag_id\":5,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"test\"},{\"tag_id\":6,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"tag_id\":7,\"corporate_statement_link_id\":1,\"name\":\"test3\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":2,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Something Happened in Our Town: A Child's Story about Racial ...\",\"link\":\"https://www.walmart.com/ip/Something-Happened-in-Our-Town-A-Child-s-Story-about-Racial-Injustice-Hardcover-9781433828546/718225519\",\"domain\":\"www.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":3,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Advancing Our Work on Racial Equity\",\"link\":\"https://corporate.walmart.com/newsroom/2020/06/12/advancing-our-work-on-racial-equity\",\"domain\":\"corporate.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":4,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Injustice : Exposing the Racial Agenda of the Obama Justice ...\",\"link\":\"https://www.walmart.com/ip/Injustice-Exposing-the-Racial-Agenda-of-the-Obama-Justice-Department/15905044\",\"domain\":\"www.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":5,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Making a Difference in Racial Equity: Walmart CEO Doug McMillon's ...\",\"link\":\"https://corporate.walmart.com/equity\",\"domain\":\"corporate.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":6,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Dog Whistle Politics : How Coded Racial Appeals Have Reinvented ...\",\"link\":\"https://www.walmart.com/ip/Dog-Whistle-Politics-How-Coded-Racial-Appeals-Have-Reinvented-Racism-and-Wrecked-the-Middle-Class-Paperback-9780190229252/43190331\",\"domain\":\"www.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":7,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Factbox: Corporations Pledge $1.7 Billion to Address Racism, Injustice\",\"link\":\"https://www.usnews.com/news/top-news/articles/2020-06-09/factbox-corporations-pledge-17-billion-to-address-racism-injustice\",\"domain\":\"www.usnews.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":8,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Applicative Justice : A Pragmatic Empirical Approach to Racial ...\",\"link\":\"https://www.walmart.com/ip/Applicative-Justice-A-Pragmatic-Empirical-Approach-to-Racial-Injustice-9781442260009/47479777\",\"domain\":\"www.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":9,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Walmart facing criticism over 'All Lives Matter,' 'Irish Lives Matter' T ...\",\"link\":\"https://thehill.com/business-a-lobbying/504664-walmart-facing-criticism-over-sale-of-all-lives-matter-irish-lives-matter\",\"domain\":\"thehill.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  },
  {
    "statement": "{\"id\":10,\"company_id\":1,\"title\":\"Topics Today: Racism and Racial Justice (Paperback) - Walmart.com\",\"link\":\"https://www.walmart.com/ip/Topics-Today-Racism-and-Racial-Justice-Paperback/914848457\",\"domain\":\"www.walmart.com\",\"tags\":[]}"
  }
]
```

With this format, I couldn't pull the information from the statement and parse it so that I can then use it in angular.

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let statement of statements" routerLink="/statement-detail" [queryParams]="{id: statement.id}" class="pointer">
    <p> {{statement.title}}</p>
    <p>
        <span *ngFor="let t of statement.tags">
            <span>t.name</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <mat-divider *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>

</mat-list-item>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: That query won't produce that json...

Comment: @Shawn, Could you please elaborate? I copied and pasted the result. I'm not sure what you mean